# Pandas, selecting by column and row

Tags: python, pandas

I want to sum up all values that I select based on some function of column and row.

Another way of putting it is that I want to use a function of the row index and column index to determine if a value should be included in a sum along an axis.

Is there an easy way of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

Columns can be selected using the syntax `dataframe[<list of columns>]`. The index (row) can be used for filtering using the `dataframe.index` method.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0.1, 0.2], 'b': [0.2, 0.1]})

odd_a = df['a'][df.index % 2 == 1]
even_b = df['b'][df.index % 2 == 0]
# odd_a: 
# 1    0.2
# Name: a, dtype: float64
# even_b: 
# 0    0.2
# Name: b, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I've removed the example, because it wasn't general enough.

Comment: how general do you want it to be? and what interface do you want to end up with?

Comment: I would love to be able to do this: (lambda x,y : x[4] < func(y[0])), and then sum over columns but I realize that might not be possible.

Answer (score 2):

If `df` is your dataframe :

```
In [477]: df
Out[477]: 
   A   s2  B
0  1    5  5
1  2    3  5
2  4    5  5
```

You can access the odd rows like this :

```
In [478]: df.loc[1::2]
Out[478]: 
   A   s2  B
1  2    3  5
```

and the even ones like this:

```
In [479]: df.loc[::2]
Out[479]: 
   A   s2  B
0  1    5  5
2  4    5  5
```

To answer your question, getting even rows and column `B` would be :

```
In [480]: df.loc[::2,'B']
Out[480]: 
0    5
2    5
Name: B, dtype: int64
```

and odd rows and column `A` can be done as:

```
In [481]: df.loc[1::2,'A']
Out[481]: 
1    2
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

Comment: I've removed the example because it wasn't general enough.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be fairly general if not the cleanest implementation. This should allow applying separate functions for rows and columns depending on conditions (that I defined here in dictionaries).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

ran = np.random.randint(0,10,size=(5,5))
df = pd.DataFrame(ran,columns = ["a","b","c","d","e"])

# A dictionary to define what function is passed
d_col = {"high":["a","c","e"], "low":["b","d"]}
d_row = {"high":[1,2,3], "low":[0,4]}

# Generate list of Pandas boolean Series
i_col = [df[i].apply(lambda x: x>5) if i in d_col["high"] else df[i].apply(lambda x: x<5) for i in df.columns]

# Pass the series as a matrix
df = df[pd.concat(i_col,axis=1)]

# Now do this again for rows
i_row = [df.T[i].apply(lambda x: x>5) if i in d_row["high"] else df.T[i].apply(lambda x: x<5) for i in df.T.columns]

# Return back the DataFrame in original shape
df = df.T[pd.concat(i_row,axis=1)].T

# Perform the final operation such as sum on the returned DataFrame
print(df.sum().sum())
```